# server not starting with NoServerDefinedException (RAD/WebSphere)

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

I am using RAD 7 with WebSphere 6.1, after creating a new profile and a new server I am unable to start the server. The server fails to start with this error:

> ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSrv03 profile ADMU3100I: Reading
>   configuration for server: newserver 
>    ADMU0111E: Program exiting with
>   error:
>              com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.NoServerDefinedException: No
>              configuration defined for server: newserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implies that there is no server with the name newserver.

How did you create the profiles? If i recall correctly, if you create a standalone server profile in WAS 6.1 the name of the server is a sacred "server1".

You have to run scripts to change the name of the server from "server1" to anything meaningful. I am guessing you haven't done that.

Go to the runtimes directory of your RAD and run the command serverstatus.bat and this would list the server names for that profile (run it froom your profile's bin directory).

This should tell you the server names. Run start server from within the command line and ensure that the server runs's properly.

This is what I would do for a start to move forward

HTH

Manglu

Answer (score 0):

What command are you using to start the server here? I am assuming "newserver" is the name of profile here, so you can start the server using the following command

```
startServer server1 -profileName newserver
```

If you have only one profile then you don't need to specify profile name

```
startServer server1
```